Android webview net:ERR_TIMED_OUT
I have a web view in android that on some webpage shows error:
Webpage not available
net:ERR_TIMED_OUT
But if I put https://google.com it shows correctly. Is it some webpage setup that web view can't handle?

Are you trying to load a webpage via an HTTP or HTTPS URL?

@Amardurai its https

And is the https server that does not work a public server that work in common web browsers like Chrome?

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 

add this in manifest this would solve the problem
